# idiomatic way to sanitize a string for printing to a terminal?

Tags: c++, string, output, sanitization, idioms

I have this string in memory, which I want to print to a terminal or a log file - without getting garbage/non-printable characters which, well, cramp my style. So, instead of

```
my_output_stream << my_string;
```

I want to do

```
my_output_stream << sanitize(my_string);
```

or maybe

```
sanitize_to(my_output_stream, my_string);
```

Is there some idiomatic/standard facility for doing this?

Comment: How do you get garbage values in your string? Wouldn't it be better to check what's going in there beforehand. To sanitize you might want to check for printable characters, and replace these with s.th. human readable (like escaped character representation).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I can get them in my string due to bugs of various sorts :-)

Comment: Makes absolutely sense for a logger class or such, but as I have mentioned additionally to what was proposed in the answers, you might to give a printable representation instead of 'throwing' the unprintable chanracters away.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way would be to filter non-printables.

I know of no existing ways, but it's easy to write one: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7600114abf492f5)**

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename It>
std::string sanitize(It f, It l) { 
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (;f!=l;++f)
    {
        if((std::isgraph(*f) || std::isspace(*f)) && *f != '\r' && *f != '\n')
            oss << *f;
        else
            oss << "%" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << 
                static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*f));
    }
    return oss.str();
}

template <typename C>
std::string sanitize(C const& c) { 
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    return sanitize(begin(c), end(c));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sanitize("Hello\tworld\r\n. §1.3 \b") << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cctype library has an isprint() function that returns true if a character is printable. You could use that to check if a character in a string is printable or not, and, well, have it print the character if it's printable and do nothing if it's not.

Comment: Mark: Thanks, I know that, but I was hoping not to 'roll my own' string sanitizer. ALso, it's not clear what you should print out if the character isn't printable.

Comment: @einpoklum Indeed, you failed to make clear what should print if the character isn't printable (Get it? **you** decide the requirements). My answer - randomly - chose 'url-encoding'-style, e.g. `%08` for `\b`